# Specifying a script is Python 2 or 3 which version of Python a program is written for

Tags: python

As there are some some important differences between Python 2 and 3, what is the standard way to specify which python specification it complies with? I.e. Which version it is written for.

I know the following questions have been asked before:

- how do I know which version in of the python interpreter is running my script
- how do I make sure python version X always runs my script

But my question is different. I want to know if there's a quick human readable way of specifying the version in the comments or as metadata.

Comment: I don't know about comments, but for python packages you do this in `setup.py`. I suppose you could also use the shebang line, which is human-readable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most common way of specifying the Python version is the [shebang](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_%28Unix%29), which is the first line of the file:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# this program is run by Python 2
```

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
# Python 3
```

Comment: Python defaults to python 3 on newer systems. `/usr/bin/python2/` is a better alias.

Comment: I use `#!/usr/bin/env python` and `#!/usr/bin/env python3` respectively. I think Python3 still uses `python3` even if it's the system default because technically it's a different language.